# Form not saving correctly to Model

Tags: html, validation, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using Asp.Net Core MVC to create a form users can use to submit some information. I'm experiencing issues however with my select tag (example below). Whenever I use this form, it doesn't pass the data validation (e.g. "Please select a number" is displayed) as it always returns a blank. When I remove the RegEx in the Model, it stores a "0" in My SQL table instead.

I've been at this for quite some time now and can't figure out what's wrong in my code. My other fields (not included in the code below) work fine, but it's only this particular field that's causing issues even when used in isolated code such as this.

Create.cshtml

```
@model kpirep_dev.Models.Numbers

@{
   ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
   <title>Create</title>
   <style>
   </style>
</head>
<body>

   <hr />
   <form asp-action="Create">
       <div class="row">
           <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
               <div class="KPID">
                   <label asp-for="KPID" class="control-label">Number</label>
                   <select asp-for="KPID" name="KPID">
                       <option disabled selected value"">select a number</option>
                       <option value="1">1</option>
                       <option value="2">2</option>
                       <option value="3">3</option>
                   </select>
                   <span asp-validation-for="Number" class="text-danger"></span>
               </div>
           </div>
           <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
           <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-secondary">Back</a>
       </div>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Model.cs

```
namespace kpirep_dev.Models {
   public class Numbers {

       public int ID { get; set; }

       [RegularExpression("^[1-9][0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Please select a Number")]
       public int KPID { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Comment: NumBBer in model? this could be a reason for the issue

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo as I changed the names of some things for this topic.

Comment: Update: the actual variable is called "KPID" (not "Number"). After renaming the variable to "kpiNo" I had no more issues. My guess is since it contains "ID" it may have been conflicting with the actual ID field?

Comment: I don't see KPID in your code snippet, update it so we can discuss it further. Until then we will be just guessing

Comment: Updated it. Sorry about that, I wasn't expecting the variable names to matter in my code, so I had changed them. Having the variable 'KPID' in my model was creating issues, but renaming it to 'kpiNo' fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

first, you need to request to your Controller not to your Model.
Request way should be like this

```
View -> Controller -> Model
```

You need follow this way. You make ready your data for your Model before sent.

Comment: Question is being related to incorrect mapping of http request to c# object. Not sure if your answer is helpful to OP